# capture mouse wheel events outside qwidget

Tags: qt, mouse

I have a qwidget derived control.

I need to capture mouse wheel events outside the control / window if the mouse is button is pressed inside the control then the mouse is moved outside.

Mouse move events are captured wheel events are not.

Qt calls capturemouse when button is pressed.

I don't mind doing  specific conditional statements for this if necessary.
I am testing on Ubuntu 16.04 and intend to cross compile for windows and possibly Mac,

Answer (score 1):

Set widget focus policy to [Qt::WheelFocus](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#FocusPolicy-enum).

```
setFocusPolicy(Qt::WheelFocus);
```

Comment: That doesn't do what I want.